# NASM error with numbered labels - error : label instruction expected at start of line

Tags: assembly, nasm

```
[ORG 0x100]

    jmp start

    num1: dw 2,0,0,4,0,1,5,2,8 
    tota11: dw 0
    tota12: dw 0
    tota13: dw 0

start:  mov bx,0
    mov cx, 3
    mov ax, 0


11:     add ax, [num1+bx]
    add bx, 2
    sub cx, 1
    jnz 11

    mov  [tota11], ax

    mov bx, 6
    mov cx, 3
    mov ax, 0

12:     add ax, [num1+bx]
    add bx, 2
    add cx, 1
    jnz 12

    mov [tota12], ax
    mov bx, 12
    mov cx, 3
    mov ax, 0

13:     add ax, [num1+bx]
    add bx, 2
    add cx, 1
    jnz 13

    mov [tota13], ax

    mov ax,[total11]
    mov bx,[total12]
    mov cx,[total13]

    cmp ax, bx

    mov ax, 0x4c00
    int 0x21
```

```
sol:asm 15 error : label instruction expected at start of line
sol:asm 26 error : label instruction expected at start of line
sol:asm 36 error : label instruction expected at start of line


sol:asm 15 error : label instruction expected at start of line
```

Comment: "Valid characters in labels are letters, numbers, _, $, #, @, ~, ., and ?. The only characters which may be used as the first character of an identifier are letters, . (with special meaning: see section 3.9), _ and ?." ~ https://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.15.05/html/nasmdoc3.html#section-3.1

Answer (score 4):

The lines where you get errors are the lines where you used numbers as labels; apparently your assembler doesn't appreciate this. You may just prepend a letter to the numbers.

Comment: Underscores should be valid as well, e.g. `_11:`